# How to solve NOT NULL constraint failed: transactions_withdrawal.user_id

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to django and I've been trying to solve this problem for over 4 days, I've surfed the web and read a lot of documentation.
I know this might be a trivial problem but I need help.

This is my code:

accounts\models.py

```python
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    # first_name = None
    # last_name = None

    account_no = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        unique=True,
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1000000000),
            MaxValueValidator(9999999999)
            ]
        )

    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        blank=False,
        validators=[
                RegexValidator(
                    regex=NAME_REGEX,
                    message='Name must be Alphabetic',
                    code='invalid_first_name'
                    )
                ]
        )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        blank=False,
        validators=[
                RegexValidator(
                    regex=NAME_REGEX,
                    message='Name must be Alphabetic',
                    code='invalid_last_name'
                    )
                ]
        )

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICE)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    balance = models.DecimalField(
        default=0,
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2
        )

    objects = UserManager()

    # USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'  # use email to log in
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'account_no'  # use email to log in
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']  # required when user is created

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.account_no)
```

transactions\forms.py

```python
class WithdrawalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Withdrawal
        fields = ["amount",]
```

transactions\models.py

```python
class Withdrawal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    amount = models.DecimalField(
    decimal_places=2,
    max_digits=12,
    validators=[
          MinValueValidator(Decimal('10.00'))
          ]
      )


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

transactions\views.py

```python
class FormWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "transactions/form.html"
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(FormWizard,self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def get_form_instance(self,step):
        return self.instance_dict.get(step, None)

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

        instance = Withdrawal()
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)

        return render(self.request,"dashboard.html", {
            'form_data':form_data
        })


def process_form_data(form_list):
    instance = Withdrawal()
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    amount = form_data[0]['amount']
    user = Withdrawal.objects.create(amount=amount)
    user.save()
```

It's basically a banking webapp and I just can't get it to work, from my understanding of web surfing and documentation, I feel the form wizard is requesting the foreign key id which I don't know how to pass in.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
This is an assignment with a deadline.

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: transactions_withdrawal.user_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\paid\banking-system\transactions\views.py", line 80, in dispatch
    return super(FormWizard,self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\formtools\wizard\views.py", line 248, in dispatch
    response = super(WizardView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\formtools\wizard\views.py", line 309, in post
    return self.render_done(form, **kwargs)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\formtools\wizard\views.py", line 365, in render_done
    done_response = self.done(final_forms.values(), form_dict=final_forms, **kwargs)
  File "C:\paid\banking-system\transactions\views.py", line 89, in done
    form_data = process_form_data(form_list)
  File "C:\paid\banking-system\transactions\views.py", line 106, in process_form_data
    bank_name=bank_name, IBAN_number=IBAN_number,swift_code=swift_code)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 422, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1332, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\paid\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: transactions_withdrawal.user_id
[20/Aug/2019 00:06:55] "POST /Transactions/ HTTP/1.1" 500 197264
```

Comment: first: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you create `Withdrawal` with `amount`  but it needs also `User` (`user_id`) because it is its `ForeignKey`. Now it uses `None` as `User` but it is not allowed so you get error `NOT NULL constraint failed: transactions_withdrawal.user_id`

Comment: I've added the error trace, I'll appreciate if you can point out where I'll make that correction in the code.Thank you.

Comment: as I said before - problem is beacuse you create `Withdrawal` without `User` (user_id) - `Withdrawal.objects.create(amount=amount)` - but model needs `User` as `ForeignKey` - `class Withdrawal(models.Model): user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)`. You need something like `Withdrawal.objects.create(amount=amount, user= ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the foreign key with User model and it cannot be **NULL**!!

If below method is not class method then(in your code it is not):

```
def process_form_data(request, form_list):
    instance = Withdrawal()
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    amount = form_data[0]['amount']
    user = Withdrawal.objects.create(user=request.user, amount=amount)
    user.save()
```

else:

```
def process_form_data(self, form_list):
    instance = Withdrawal()
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    amount = form_data[0]['amount']
    user = Withdrawal.objects.create(user=self.request.user, amount=amount)
    user.save()
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Rarblack, its working perfectly now,I just  didn't know how to access that user. I'm kinda new to python/django.

Comment: Always welcome to ask when you have toubles @D.afo. Happy learnings.